# Is it possible to have a page name with two different languages?

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a page on Facebook which is written in Arabic, but people search for it using Latin characters.

Is it possible to have a page with both Arabic and English names?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can have two pages with same name but in different languages.

Suppose your pagename is Football, so you can create two pages like this:

- Football
- كرة القدم

First is in English and second is in Arabic.

Or other option is you can have only one page in English or Arabic language and you can post in different languages and make sure only certain people will be able to see your post.

For that when you are posting, it shows **Public** option, click on that dropdown and select **Location/Language**. Type in the countries or languages of the people you want to see your post. Post will only show up in News Feed or on your Page for people in the countries you choose or for people who speak the languages you specify.

See this to understand [How to control who can see Page's posts?](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/352402648173466).

<sup><sub>Note: My Arabic language can be wrong. I don't know Arabic.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, i apologize i didn't answer before. What i wish is to have one single page with 2 different languages. that isn't possible is it?

Comment: No..that is not possible as of now as per my knowledge.